# how can I get location href in all entered urls by js

Tags: javascript, js-routes

I am actually looking for a way to **get all the URLs entered** so that I can redirect the wrong URLs to a 404 page.

when I hit different url s like `localhost:0000/details`, because `location.href` is in index.html, this code is not executed. and I can't figure out the URL to redirect the user to the desired page.

Comment: If you want to do this in a standard web server in purely HTML, I don't believe this is possible. I imagine you would configure your server to capture any unhandled URL's and then serve a specific page in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer in your case will depend on how your are serving your HTML pages, but generally, you would configure you're server to handle a `404 not found` response by sending back a specific HTML page.

[See this section on the MDN '404 Not Found' page regarding custom error pages.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404#custom_error_pages) This section specifically refers to the Apache server, where you would add the following to a `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /<your-page-name-here>.html
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, we should not look for a solution through HTML and js, and this case can only be controlled through the server.

if I were using GitHub pages, you should create a file called 404.html in the root of the repository so that all 404 errors are redirected to this page.

[Creating a custom 404 page for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site)

if you are using the Apache server, read @damonholden 's answer.